# How to get items from both master and web Context in PowerShell Extensions without using Get-Item?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I want to get all the items from both master and web database using `Find-Item` cmdlet and run in one Powershell script. I'd also rather not use `Get-Item` cmdlet for performance reasons. Any inputs will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Here's the script that I've tried:

```
$master = Find-Item -Index sitecore_master_index  @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_group"; Value = "{C89D37FF-3919-4D89-9925-948B67BD22D9}"}  

$web = Find-Item -Index sitecore_web_index  @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_group"; Value = "{C89D37FF-3919-4D89-9925-948B67BD22D9}"}  

$result = $web | Where {$master.ID -NotContains $_.ID}  
$result
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the script you're trying to run? Also, it would be helpful to mention in your question that you'd rather not use `Get-Item` due to performance reasons.

Comment: If you just need to compare which items are missing, you can use Compare-Object. Provide the field name which you want to compare and you'll never need to call Get-Item. Check out the #module-spe channel on https://Sitecore.chat if you would like to have conversations about the module.

Comment: @MichaelWest Yes, I would just like to compare which items are missing between my master and web databases. I noticed the Context tab only runs the script in one specific database only. I need my script to run in both databases. I also signed up in the channel, just waiting for approval. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, you could do the following to compare the results:

```
$criteria = @(
    @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_template"; Value = "{DAF085E8-602E-43A6-8299-038FF171349F}"}
)

$masterResults = Find-Item -Index "sitecore_master_index" -Criteria $criteria | Select-Object -Property ItemId,DatabaseName
$webResults = Find-Item -Index "sitecore_web_index" -Criteria $criteria | Select-Object -Property ItemId,DatabaseName

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $masterResults -DifferenceObject $webResults -Property ItemId
```

### Update

From the screenshot below you can see that the objects in the `$webResults` variable reflects results from the **web** database.

[image: Results]

From the results above, you want to "get" the items from the database, then you'll want to pass the items through `Initialize-Item`.

[image: Proof that it's from Web]

Comment: thanks for this Sir, but the script you provided is pulling data from the 'sitecore_master_index' only. No data from the web index has been pulled.

Comment: Assuming you changed the item Id in the script, then webResults is empty because the item does not exist. This is as you would expect, right?

Comment: No Sir, I'm expecting to get data from both master and web, regardless if I get it from both of the databases or through index. The script above only runs on the context item set in the Context tab of the ISE. I noticed that regardless of what index name (e.g sitecore_master_index) i will use on my script, it will only get data from whatever context item i set, I can't set two context items. If that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Maia, I'm not clear on what else your script is doing for you to get data from the context database. From the example I provided above, it demonstrates that items really do come from the web index and web database.

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you for the update. So even though in my Context item it is set to master:\content\Home, I still get objects from web index and web database, right? I can explicitly compare objects from both indices regardless of what is set on the Context item?

Comment: Hello Sir @MichaelWest I have a question, I already got the web item from the GUID I used. But is there a way  I could also get it's children? The 'Get-ChildItem' seems not working after I piped it with my '$webResults'

Comment: Notice in my example the use of Initialize-Item. This will retrieve the item. Using that item you can get the children. Another option is to get the  ItemId from each in the $webResults collection and then query the children.

Comment: Here's what I've tried Sir @MichaelWest. But it's pulling the 'sitecore_master_index' data instead of the web.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg8ml.png

Comment: I got my desired result Sir. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's great. Anything I need to change for my answer to be marked accepted?

Comment: As I've mentioned in the support chat group Sir, there's no need to change. This is very much acceptable. Thanks a lot! :)

P.S. I also had no idea before that there's an accept button for answers. Hehe my apologies!